# How to execute commands after delete a row from GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I tried by to handle `RowCommand`. But it executed before deletion is done.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
    if e.CommandName = "delete"
        'do something here
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own command and then order the actions as you wish.  Take a look at this:  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/syedshakeer/rowcommand-event-in-gridview/